# Is there a way to generate a random matrix that satisfies a given linear matrix inequality (LMI)?

Tags: random-matrices, linear-matrix-inequality

The title is self-evident, I think. For example, we could generate a $n \times n$ random rank-$1$ positive semidefinite matrix by generating a random vector $x$ and $x x^T$ will be the random matrix we want. Now if there is a given linear matrix inequality, i.e., a spectrahedron, is there a way to generate a matrix that is included in the spectrahedron?

So to make it more clear. Consider symmetric matrix space $S^n$,we can generate a random positive definite matrix $X$ in this space by, for example, generate some matrix $A$ and let $X=A^TA$,but what if I want to generate a random positive definite matrix in a certain subspace of the matrix space, such as defined by a Linear Matrix Inequality (as Omnomnomnom suggested in the comments). Is there a way to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: This could be made clearer.

Comment: I suppose you're specifically referring to [linear matrix inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_matrix_inequality)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't dig into details but judging from the title it should be what I am looking for. Or at least give me a understanding of what can be achieved.[Uniform sampling in semi-algebraic sets](http://homepages.laas.fr/henrion/papers/sampling.pdf)

Comment: Put your answer (that is not an answer) into your above question.